# Absolute component size in movieclip

Tags: flash, movieclip

If a drag a component from the library into a movieclip and then drag the movieclip to the stage. Now if i resize the movieclip, can I set the component with a fixed width or height?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do that programmatically by giving the component an instance name, for example `theComponent` and then put something like this code in the movieclip that is on stage:

```
onClipEvent(load) {
    this.theComponent._width = 50;
    this.theComponent._height = 50;
}
```

This way, when the mc loads, it will set its component's dimensions to 50x50.